# Trouble Installing tdodbc in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, odbc, teradata

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm trying to follow the guide here:

http://crashthatch.tumblr.com/post/66957708538/teradata-odbc-connection-using-python-on-ubuntu

To install the teradata odbc driver on Ubuntu. The blog post is a bit old and so I'm actually using a different version of the driver:

ODBC Driver 16.00.00.02

I downloaded and unpacked the different files and converted them to deb using alien, as instructed, but

When I attempt to run:

```
sudo dpkg -i tdodbc1600_16.00.00.01-2_all.deb
```

I get the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing package tdodbc1600 (--install):
cannot compute MD5 hash for file '/opt/teradata/client/16.00/lib/tdwalletdir.dpkg-new': failed to read (Is a directory)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tdodbc1600
```

Does anyone know what I can do here?

I am going to try using the version of the driver mentioned in the blog (14.10.00.00-1), and see what happens, and will update this post accordingly. In the mean time, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I am now using the driver version 14.00.00.09 following the same blog.

Before running:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pyodbc odbcinst
```

I need to install:

```
sudo apt-get install odbcinst1debian2 libodbc1
```

I was then following the instructions to:

> Add the teradata files to ldconfig, by creating a new file, /etc/ld.so.conf.d/Zteradata.conf with the contents:
>
> /opt/teradata/client/14.10/odbc_64/lib,
>      /opt/teradata/client/14.10/tdicu/lib64,
>      /opt/teradata/teragss/linux-x8664/14.10.00.06/lib

But I noticed although the first two directories exist (with the version number being 14.00 instead of 14.10) I don't have the last directory.

I have a folder called:

```
/opt/teradata/teragss/site/linux-x8664
```

but it is empty.

Comment: Looks like the installer files are broken. Any reason you don't want to use a thin JDBC driver instead?

Comment: I'm not familiar with what a thin JDBC driver is, but I'll look into it. I am instead going the route of having a friend set up a docker environment for me with the drivers installed.

Comment: Here's a link for you: 

http://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/jdbc-driver

You will need to download the zip and extract two jar files in order to connect. Path is irrelevant, as long as the main program can see it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to install Teradata ODBC Driver 16.00.00.03 (http://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/odbc-driver/linux)

I tried to install it on Ubuntu 14.04 and the installation of tdodbc `sudo dpkg -i tdodbc1600_16.00.00.03-2_all.deb` didn't fail. It may be related to the different Ubuntu version (14.04 and not 16.04) but more likely it's a fix they they made to the rpm

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. System requirements are SUSE/RedHat/Oracle. Sounds like Teradata does not support Ubuntu, and Alien cannot convert properly?

From the [16.00.00.02 README](http://downloads.teradata.com/download/files/7455/200260/1/tdodbc1600__linux_indep.16.00.00.02-1.txt):

```
3.0 Requirements
    3.1 System
        RedHat Enterprise Linux 6.x on EM64T & Opteron    
        RedHat Enterprise Linux 7.x on EM64T & Opteron    
        SUSE Enterprise Linux 11    on EM64T & Opteron
        SUSE Enterprise Linux 12    on EM64T & Opteron
        ORACLE Enterprise Linux 6.x on EM64T & Opteron
        ORACLE Enterprise Linux 7.x on EM64T & Opteron
```